# How to Query two tables with similar data and Group the Result by table field in JAVA?

Tags: java, sql, select

I'm trying to perform analysis in a certain system.  The system is supposed to perform analysis by querying two or more tables from the database and then display the total result Grouped by a field.

This is a Java based system using SQL as its Database. I have tried to use UNION, UNION ALL but it is not giving satisfying results.

Below is Table1

```
id    itemID     ItemName     entryTime
1      GAR001     PhoneAG       ""
2      GAR004     PCLG          ""
3      GAR009     ELECT         ""    
...
```

Below is Table2

```
id    itemID     ItemName     entryTime    issuedate
1      GAR001     PhoneAG       ""           ""
2      GAR001     PhoneAG       ""           ""
3      GAR009     ELECT         ""           ""    
...
```

I have tried using the following

```
public ObservableList<PieChart.Data> getItemAnalysis(){
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String st1 = "SELECT itemID, COUNT(itemID) FROM table1 GROUP BY itemID UNION ALL SELECT itemID, COUNT(itemID) FROM table2 GROUP BY itemID";
        System.out.println(st1);
        ResultSet rs = execQuery(st1);
        try{

            if(rs.next()){
                String itemId = rs.getString("itemID");
                int count = rs.getInt(2);

                data.add(new PieChart.Data(itemId + "(" + count + ")", count));


            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return data;

    }
```

On Result Return. It returns

```
GAR001(1),
GAR004(1),
GAR009(1),
GAR001(2),
GAR009(1).
```

I expect the Result Return to be

```
GAR001(3)
GAR004(1)
GAR009(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying a `union all` between two grouped queries. Instead, you should `union all` the raw data, and then group it:

```sql
SELECT   itemID, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT itemID
          FROM   table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT itemID
          FROM   table2) t
GROUP BY itemID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You have really saved me after having many sleepless nights.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sub-queries

`SELECT DISTINCT itemID , COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
 FROM (SELECT itemID 
       FROM table1 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT itemID 
       FROM table2) as T 
 GROUP BY itemID;`

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to edit your SQL statement, which is why you are getting those results. @Mureinik posted the correct SQL. I went ahead and plugged that into your code to give you a solution which should work.

```
public ObservableList<PieChart.Data> getItemAnalysis(){
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        sql = "SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT itemID FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT itemID FROM table2) t GROUP BY itemID"
        System.out.println(sql);
        ResultSet rs = execQuery(sql);
        try{

            if(rs.next()){
                String itemId = rs.getString("itemID");
                int count = rs.getInt(2);

                data.add(new PieChart.Data(itemId + "(" + count + ")", count));


            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return data;

    }
```

Comment: @Garande I'm happy it worked for you. Please mark this answer as "correct" so other users can use it in the future!